# The command for generating the number of function evaluation

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab code of a nonlinear conjugate gradient method. The problem is I cannot get the number of function evaluation. Please can someone help me. I am willing to share my code.

```matlab
function HCGM
clc
n = input('Please enter small n (dimension): ');
rho = 0.0001;
sigma = 0.9;
x0 = zeros(n,1); % Setup x

t=1;
x0 = initx(n);
G = g(x0,n);
D = -G;
k = 0;
normGIni = norm(G);
p = '6 - Quadratic Diagonal Perturbed Function; Initialvalue (0.5, 0.5, ..., 0.5)T   ';

tol = 10^-6; % Begin with

fid = fopen('ArmijoProb38.txt', 'a+');
fprintf(fid,'\n Result of New hybrid CG Method for Problem %60s Dimension: %d Tolerance: %5.1e\n',p, n, tol);
fclose(fid);
%if normGIni < 10^-9*normGIni
 if normGIni < tol
        fprintf('ArmijoLineSearch: tolerance on gradient satisfied at initial iterate\n')
    fid = fopen('ArmijoProb38.txt', 'a+');
 fprintf(fid,'ArmijoLineSearch: tolerance on gradient satisfied at initial iterate\n');
 fclose(fid);
end;

format long
fprintf('-----------  Iteration Begins  ------------------------------  \n')
fid = fopen('ArmijoProb38.txt', 'a+');
fprintf(fid,'  Itr       F(x)            NormG           GtD           Alpha           Beta     \n');
fclose(fid);
tic                                 %Start


while norm(G)>= tol

    Gnorm = norm(G);
    F = f(x0,n);
    GtD = G'*D;
    alp = StrongWolfeLineSearch(x0,F,GtD,D,rho,sigma,n);
    x1 = x0 + alp.*D;
    delx = x1-x0;
    G0 = G;
    G = g(x1,n);
    beta = (G'*G - (norm(G)/norm(G0))*abs(G'*G0))/(G0'*G0); %MVPRP

    D0=D;
    D = -G+beta.*D0;

 fid = fopen('ArmijoProb38.txt', 'a+');
 fprintf(fid,'   %d     %d    %10.4e   %10.4e    %10.4e    %10.4e\n', k, F, Gnorm, GtD, alp, beta);

 fclose(fid);   
    x0 = x1;
    k = k+1;
end;

iter = k;
normG = norm(G);
% F = round(f(x0,n));
 F = f(x0,n);% x0;

t = toc;                        %finish
%fprintf('Iter %d: F(x) = %d, Gnorm = %6.2e, GtD = %5.1e, Alpha = %e, Beta = %e, Time = %7.3f\n', iter, F, normG, GtD, alp, beta, t)
fprintf('Iter %d: F(x) = %d, Gnorm = %6.2e, Time = %7.3f\n', iter, F, normG, t)
fid = fopen('ArmijoProb38.txt', 'a+');
%fprintf(fid,'\n Iter %d: F(x) = %d, Gnorm = %6.2e, GtD = %5.1e, Alpha = %e, Beta = %e, Time = %7.3f\n', iter, F, normG, GtD, alp, beta, t)
fprintf(fid,'\n Iter %d: F(x) = %d, Gnorm = %6.2e, Time = %7.3f\n', iter, F, normG, t)

fclose(fid);
```

I want to know the lines of commands to add to estimate the number of function evaluate. I am looking at doing this for several variants of the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the number of times that `function HCGM` is being called you can add a [global variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html), called fn_count or something, which you increment at the beginning of every function call.

However very likely you are better off using the [built in profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) for what you are doing.

If you are asking for something else please rephrase your question to make that more clear

Comment: Dear sgilen, thank you for your reply. If you run the code provided (by first adding the lines of code below that give the objective function and its gradient definitions), you will get the values to the number of iterations, f(x), gnorm and the cpu time. However, my aim is to get the number of function and gradient evaluations (my function is defined as y=f(x,n) and my gradient defined as y=g(x,n)). These values should be integers.

Comment: The additional line of code are:``` function alpha = StrongWolfeLineSearch(x0, F, GtD, D, rho,sigma,n)  
alpha = 0;  
t = 1; 
done=0;
while ~done
    x = x0 + t*D; 
    F1 = f(x,n);
    G1 = g(x,n);
    if F1 > F + rho*t*GtD && abs(G1'*D) > sigma*abs(GtD)
        t=0.5*t;
    else
        alpha = t;
        done=1;
    end
end
function y = f(x,n)
c = 1:n;
y = (sum(x(c))).^2+1/100*(sum(c*(x(c)).^2));
function y = g(x,n)
c = 1:n;
yy = 2*sum(x(c))+1/50*c*x(c);
y = yy';

function x0 = initx(n)
 i = 1:n;
 xx(i) = 0.5;
 x0 = xx';
 ```

Comment: Hi Josh, my answer is still the same, you can add a globe to StrongWolfeLineSearch (or any function that you are interested in) that tracks the number of function calls. Or you can use the built in profiler which should also track this information.